# Is it possible to overwrite sqlite db in IPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, sqlite

I have created the application which is based on Sqlite database.

So in my app, initially i have created the Sqlite db with one data and i have added that db into my "Resource" folder in my project.

While app running at first time, checking db in Documents folder(Sandbox) if no file means, copy the db from Resource to Document folder.

After that every insert and delete operations performing on Db in Document folder only. not on db in Resource folder.

So, i have inserted 50 items in db and then i have deleted the app from Simulator(or) device.

When deleting app, db also deleted with that.

My question is ==> How to overwrite the Sqlite db(in Resource folder) with db(in Documents folder) when every updation in app(insert, delete)?

because db file in Documment folder getting update while inserting items into that.

I am using XCode 4.2 with iOS 5 sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** change the **Resource bundle** once you created (i.e app file). You cannot overwrite the SQLite db into resource folder of your bundle.

If you still want to keep previous db then just copy it from simulator path and replace whenever you clean and build the app.

**EDIT:**

You can go to **/Users//Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/*"Simulator version you use"*/Application/*"check all folder to find your app inside this folder"*/ "YOUR APP.app"**

Then **Right Click** APP file and Click **Show Package Content**. Now you will be able to see the resources you used in App file. You can search your DB and **BACKUP/REPLACE** it.

Comment: Thanks Dshah.. You mean Replace db file through code (or) simply copy that to Resource folder by manual..

Comment: Can u post sample code to replace the db file?..its will be very helpful

Comment: For simulator it is easy to replace the db file. see Edit section.  But never try to replace in Device. Apple does not allow this.

Answer (score 1):

First off the database file in the app bundle (resource folder) is read only and can't be changed by the app.

Second when an update is installed, all the files in the app bundle get replaced by the files in the update. The files in the document directory aren't touched.

if you need to update the database file in the document directory you will need to implement an update method some where and keep track of the versie of the database used.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can **modify any resource present inside the application bundle**.
That's why we copy the database file to the documents directory of the application, so we can modify the file. 
If you want to preserve data, you backup the data using the **iCloud** service.

Comment: All files in the document directory are automatically backed up by iCloud. There is no need to add extra backup methods.

Comment: @rckoenes AFAIK, nothing is backed up until and unless you have enabled iCloud services for the app.

Comment: No the [documentation of Apple](http://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/) clearly states that files in the document directory arre backed up to iCloud." ***1. Only documents and other data that is user-generated, or that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application, should be stored in the <Application_Home>/Documents directory and will be automatically backed up by iCloud.***

Comment: @rckoenes I agree with your point, but what i'm trying to say is, nothing will be backed up, if the iCloud entitlements are not there for the app (i.e iCloud is not enabled).

Comment: No, i've got mutiple apps with out the iCloud entitlements and they do show up in the iCloud data usage on the settings app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this by opening another handle for the database in your resource folder and perform the operation for that too. I assume you need it only when you run it in simulator for convenience.

You cannot do this when you run in device.

Answer (score 0):

Its true that there is no way to copy that document folder data again to resource bundle, so i will suggest u to take a backup of that db before deleting the application from simulator or from the device.